# HTML message or login pages intercepting web service requests

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, response, webclient

I am busy working on a mobile application that retrieves data from a web service.
Ofcourse everything is working perfectly, I get everything I need to and I can consume the services without much effort... on the emulator.

However, when I move over to testing this application on the device, instead of getting back the data that I am expecting I am getting a website returned. How am I supposed to handle this?

Currently I am using this to call my service: (using system.net - I dont know if this is what I should be using on windows phone 7 either)

```
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
string strURI = "http://www.google.co.za";
proxy.OpenReadCompleted +=
        new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(proxy_openreadcompleted);
proxy.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(strURI));
```

Please note: I am not really calling google, it is just an example. So anyways I am expecting my JSON to be returned, instead I am getting a message from the service provider to change mobile options... I can put this into isolated storage and render it with a browser, however I do not know what the source of the message is so when you click on a button, the forms use relative URLs, so instead of it doing what it is intened to do I just see what it is trying to call.

Is there anyway to get the source of the response? I am looking for a source like http://vodafonelive.mobi/ or something like that. If someone can tell me what to do I would greatly appreciate it, my current thinking is that if I can identify the source I can create a webbrowser task so that my application does not need to handle this, however... since I am calling a specific source I don't know how to identify where the response is comming from.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The way that iPhones do this is to pop up an HTML browser that the user then has to log in or click through, then hide it again when you get the web service response you were expecting. I'd be surprised if there wasn't an easy way to do this on Windows Phone too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after spending some time on this, I finally found a way that I could get a response uri (where the response was comming from) by using another method to do the call to the service:

So basically this is the call:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURI);
var result = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
```

So in the function ResponseCallBack function I do something like this:

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
```

which then allows me to check the response uri (the source of the intercepted message) and have the native browser handle the html that I was not expecting.

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = response.ResponseUri;
```

Thanks for the help though, hopefully this will help someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to differences in the user agent of the emulator and the device. Check what is sent or set this explicitly to ensure that the 2 behave in the same way. To ensure the server doesn't try and redirect to a different location.

Alternatively, it could be a mobile operator proxy being "helpful" and adjusting the request that goes over their network.